# Why does the upper and lower bounds theorem of polynomials work for the modulus of complex zeroes?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

My math professor told us that the upper and lower bounds theorem of polynomials (pictured) applies not only to rational roots, but also to the modulus of complex zeroes. They were unable to come up with an explanation for why this works, and I do not grasp this concept at all.

Why/how does the bounds theorem apply just as well to to complex zeroes as it does to rational zeroes? How does the modulus come into play at all for that matter?

[Bounds Theorem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02WCt.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A proof is given in the Wikipedia article on [geometrical properties of polynomial roots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometrical_properties_of_polynomial_roots):

First, if $|z| \leq 1$ then clearly $|z| \leq 1 + M$, so we will assume $|z| > 1$. Then since $a_n z^n + \ldots + a_0 = 0$, we have:

$$\begin{eqnarray} |a_n| |z^n| & = & |a_n z^n| \\
& = & \left| \sum_{i = 0}^{n - 1} a_i z^i \right| \\
& \leq & \sum_{i = 0}^{n - 1} |a_i z^i| \\
& \leq & \max |a_i| \sum_{i = 0}^{n - 1} |z|^i \\
& = & \max |a_i| \frac{|z|^n - 1}{|z| - 1} \\
& \leq & \max |a_i| \frac{|z|^n}{|z| - 1} \\
\implies |z| - 1 & \leq & \max \frac{|a_i|}{|a_n|}
\end{eqnarray}$$

Comment: Thank you! It's a bit over my head but it seems to make sense. I can't upvote account is too young.

Comment: You should be able to accept the answer by clicking a tick under the score, thanks!